# Calling Frege From Java Doesn't Match Number of Parameters

Tags: java, compilation, frege

I have Frege code as follows (mostly, just pay attention to the type signature for getDatabase)

```
module fregeHelper.FregeCode where 

--Java's String.split method
pure native split :: String -> String -> JArray String

--Java's ArrayList<t>
data ArrayList t =native java.util.ArrayList where
    native new :: () -> STMutable s (ArrayList t)
    native add::Mutable s (ArrayList t)-> t -> ST s ()

getDatabase::String->(IO (STMutable s (ArrayList (String, String))))
getDatabase s = do
        fileContents <- readFile s
        let processedData = map ((\x->(elemAt x 0, elemAt x 1)) . (flip split ";")) . lines $ fileContents
        return $ fold foldAdd (ArrayList.new ()) processedData
    where
        foldAdd::ST s (Mutable s (ArrayList t)) -> t -> ST s (Mutable s (ArrayList t))
        foldAdd list elem = list >>= \x->(ArrayList.add x elem >> return x)
```

Then from Java I want to define the following function thusly (where DATABASE is a string constant):

```
private void readDatabase() {
    myList = Delayed.<ArrayList<TTuple2>>forced(
            fregeHelper.FregeCode.getDatabase(DATABASE));
}
```

However, this gives me a `java.lang.ClassCastException: frege.prelude.PreludeBase$TST$1 cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList`

Through experimentation, I had to change the code to be

```
private void readDatabase() {
    fighters = Delayed.<ArrayList<TTuple2>>forced(
            fregeHelper.FregeCode.getDatabase(DATABASE)
            .apply(null)
            .apply(null)
            );
}
```

I've put null in the latter applies just to show that it doesn't matter what I pass in. I have no idea why I have to apply the function three times (I can't just immediately force evaluation). Is there any way I can either remove the applies or have some rationalization as to why they're necessary?
(Note: using .result() doesn't help the case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that in this implementation, a ST action is represented as a "function object", where the method that implements the accompagnied function ignores it argument.

It may help the understanding to recall the definition of ST:

```
abstract data ST s a = ST (s -> a) where ...
```

First thing to note is that the `data` would actually be written `newtype` in Haskell. So `ST` is just a type renaming, that is, an ST action is actually a function.

However, the `abstract` makes sure you cannot look through the `ST` data constructor and hence cannot run the function directly from Frege code.

This explains why, from Java, after applying the arguments to a function that returns a `ST` action, one needs to apply that extra argument to the result, which is, as we've seen, nothing but another function.

So, why then, do you have to do this two times in your code? Because `IO` is (from the top of my head):

```
type IO = ST RealWorld
```

and `STMutable` is

```
type STMutable s x = ST s (Mutable s x)
```

So the problem lies in your `getDatabase` function, which returns an `IO` action, which, when executed, returns an ST action, which, when executed, returns a mutable ArrayList.

This is probably not what you wanted. And I guess you struggled a while with the last line in `getDatabase`, which should probably read:

```
list <- ArrayList.new ()
foldM (\xs\x -> ArrayList.add xs x >> return xs) list processedData
```

the return type being then

```
IO (Mutable RealWorld ArraList)
```

or just

```
IOMutable ArrayList
```

Another point besides: you should not need to re-introduce `split`, it is already there. You could write that line that takes the semicolon delimitted input lines apart:

```
[ (a,b) | line <- lines fileContent, [a,b] <- ´;´.splitted line ]
```

See also http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/frege/java/util/Regex.html#Regex.splitted and http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/frege/java/util/Regex.html#Regex.split

### Addition

Dierks answer makes an interesting point that we should have an utility function for running ST (or IO) actions from Java code. In fact, there is such a function, its name is `ST.performUnsafe` (in Frege) and it is known in Haskell as `unsafePerformIO`.

In fact, using this function would make Java code more robust against changes in the implementation and is therefore strongly recommended in place of the `.apply(null)` code used here.

Comment: Great, thanks for the response. I'm not sure how all the definitions for IO/ST/Mutable/IOMutable/MutableIO etc etc are nested and connected. If there's a resource for that, I'd appreciate it.
Also, ST.performUnsafe is on the frege side -- is there a safe, robust way to force execution from the Java side?

Comment: @Crazycolorz5 well, it is all documented in http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/frege/prelude/PreludeIO.html  -  For seeeing how some expression could be translated to Java, enter the expression in the REPL and use the :java command. For example, :load and import your Frege module, then type `ST.performUnsafe (getDatabase "foo")` nd when this is ok with the type checker, type `:java` The code corresponding to your expression is shown near the end.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that others can provide better answers but the reason for what looks like extra parameters that you have to pass when forcing evaluation of the Delayed are the IO and STMutable types.

I came across the same issue here: https://github.com/Frege/FregeFX/blob/f2f548071afd32a08e9b24f6fb6bbece74d4213b/fregefx/src/main/java/org/frege/FregeFX.java#L19-L19

It may be worth considering a utility method "deeplyForced" (?) that shields the Java developer from these details.

Comment: This utility method does exist, and its name is `IO.performUnsafe` (I should add this to my answer). But the point here is that OP nested two levels of ST (inadvertly, I guess).